# How can load my text file with float type not string type in python?

Tags: python

It is a txt file with 99255 numbers in a row.

This is some example of txt file :

```
    -0.640157 
    -0.556037 
    -0.692255 
    -0.553077 
    -0.932098 
    -0.749993 
    -0.713643 
    -0.838611 
    -0.734945 
    -0.837929 
    .
    .
    .
```

I want to load these numbers in float type and assign them in np.array form.

Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`numpy`](https://numpy.org/) directly

```
import numpy as np
filename = "/path/to/file"
array = np.loadtxt(filename, np.float)
```

Comment: thanks for your comment. I created an ex.txt file consisting of 1 2 3 4 and tried to substitute your code. But when I try to print to see if it was assigned successfully, I get a strange result like [8.035657e-09 5.517073e-31]. May I ask why this is happening?

Comment: I am sorry for the mistake, the function should be `loadtxt` not `fromfile`. I have edited it alreay

Comment: @InsungLee  If the answer helped, please consider accepting it

Answer (score 0):

Read line by line and convert to float each element. Append them in a list, then convert the list.

```
import numpy as np

with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    line = f.readLine().strip('\n')
    l = []
    while line:
        l.append(float(line))
        line = f.readLine().strip('\n')

np.asarray(l)
```